# How can I automate password entry for a shell script?

Tags: bash

I am using openvpn.
To execute the vpn I enter in my terminal the following command string: sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/ca-mon.prod.surfshark.com_udp.ovpn
Then I am required to enter my password.
Openvpn requires sudo or it won't work.

I created a shell script hoping to eliminate the need to type my password.
after searching for solutions I read tha including "NOPASSWD" would solve my issue.  However,  NOPASSWD isn't recognized, the script stops with an error on NOPASSWD.

I thought maybe NOPASSWD might only work on BASH so I changed the script for BASH.   No difference, still errors out on NOPASSWD.

I'm obviously doing something wrong as I keep reading that it should work.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

My script that works but requires my password after execution:
#!/bin/bash
cd /etc/openvpn
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/us-dtw.prod.surfshark.com_udp.ovpn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your /etc/sudoers file, add

```
yourusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /"The REAL PATH of your openvpn file"
```

Then try to rerun the script.

Comment: That did it, thanks so much.

Comment: You can accpet my answer to make it clear for other people who has the same problem :-)